# Triggering Actions in a sequence Python Reaper

Tags: python, sequence, keystroke, reaper

I need help with a script for the DAW Reaper using Python. I don't really know programming but this is what I have so far. What I need to accomplish is to to type what has been copied into the clipboard, then after it finishes typing all the content, press the "Enter" key  and finally wait 1 second and press a hotkey (ctrl + R). I have tried some functions that use delays but the delays is always being applied to the typewrite function as well so by the time the content finishes typing the hot key has already been pressed. Additionally if there is a way to just paste instead of type from clipboard, that would be best, but I have not been successful with that ( simulating pressing ctrl + v didn't work)

```
import time
import pyautogui
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key

# Add a delay of 5 seconds before running the script
time.sleep(0.5)

from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
result = root.clipboard_get()

x, y = pyautogui.position()
pyautogui.typewrite(result)

def main():

    # Press Enter key
    keyboard = Controller()
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```